# Applying Benzecrì correction with FactoMiner

Tags: r, statistics, correspondence-analysis, factominer, mca

I have a dataset like the one below (with qualitative variable) and I need to apply Benzecrì correction on the dataframe that i will use for the MCA or on the function res.mca,

| gender | Income |
| --- | --- |
| Male | from 10-15 |
| Female | from 15-20 |

Ecc...

This is the function I'm using for MCA

```
res.mca <- MCA(df, ncp = 5, graph = TRUE, method = "Burt")
```

I think I probably need to apply a function or something, can someone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mca <- MCA(mydata)
#Benzecri correction
p <- nrow(mca$eig)+1
lambda <- mca$eig[,1]
lambdaC <- lambda
lambdaT <- which(lambda>=1/p)

#eig.val corrected
lambdaC=(p/(p-1))*(lambdaC[lambdaT]-(1/p))^2

#percentage of variances explained per axes
ptd <- (lambdaC/sum(lambdaC))

#cumulated percentage of explained variance
cum <- cumsum(lambdaC/sum(lambdaC))
correc <- cbind(lambdaC,ptd,cum*100)
correc = as.data.frame(correc)
correc
```

or use

```
mca.eigen.fix()
```

from

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ExPosition/html/mca.eigen.fix.html